# How to un-hide image if UIWebView URL is not www.example.com

Tags: url, uiwebview, hyperlink

I am making a app which opens local files and navigates through them. Is there code I can use which will scan the URL and check if it is a certain URL and if it isn't it will run a command such as;

```
[homebutton setHidden:NO];
```

The point of this is to make a 'back/home' button appear if the user navigates to another site rather than the build in pages.

I would really appreciate some help, thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [UIWebViewDelegate methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to monitor the URLs that are being loaded. That way you can easily hide or show the button as appropriate for the current URL.

Comment: Can you explain in further detail how I would do this as I am a newbie? Some sample code would be appreciated, thank you very much :-)

Comment: I recommend working through [this tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/12/19/iphone-coding-learning-about-uiwebviews-by-creating-a-web-browser/). You'll see that they start/stop the activity indicator with the delegate methods and also check if the URL the user clicked on begins with "http". That's the place where you could do the checks for your website URL and enable/disable the button.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I've done that like this but how can I get the command - if not @"http://www.example.com"; -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        
        NSURL *URL = [request URL];
        
        if ([[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"http://www.example.com"]) {
            
            [homebutton setHidden:NO];
            
        }
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

Comment: I followed the instructions on that page and changed the command in the if section to [homebutton setHidden:NO]; but with no luck, I tried it with http:// like on the example but the home button didn't appear when the UIWebView showed a http page

Comment: How did you set up your button? Is it properly connected to an outlet of your class?

Comment: Yes it is, I have done a [homebutton setHidden:NO]; command on another part of my app just to test it when another button is touched and it works perfectly so not sure what went wrong?

Comment: Just added webView.delegate = self; and NSLog appears now (I've added that to test if it works) but no links work at all, including my local file ones?

Comment: Any solutions? Is there any more sample code which may work for me? Thank you.

Comment: You need to return "YES" in the `...shouldStartLoad...` method. Otherwise the web view won't let you go anywhere. Are you doing that?

Comment: Nope, can you direct me on how to do that please because like I said, I'm a newbie to all this and can only do the basics! :-)

Comment: To return YES, simply ... `return YES;` :) Have you checked out Aaron Hillegas' book on iPhone programming? It's a fabulous way to get up to speed: http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/iphone_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide